# Drupal to Drupal Migration

Tags: drupal, migration

I am attempting to migrate hosts and am having issues migrating from one Drupal instance to another.  I have a multi-site install.  I am attempting to maintain the files/code as well as databases.  I have transferred the files from the instance of Drupal from my old server to the new server.  I have exported the databases via phpmyadmin and imported them back in with cli.  For some reason the homepages for my sites work but the internal pages do not. When i try to navigate to a page I get The requested URL was not found. I have installed and ran a new instance of drupal 6 (same version) on the new server and it seems to work fine.  I assume it is something I am doing wrong with the porting process?  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you transfer the `.htaccess` file(s) too ?

Those are "hidden" (their name is starting with a '.'), and not shown by default by some FTP transfer software...

*(I've seen exactly this problem a couple of days ago, and getting the .htaccess from the old server and putting it on the new one saved the day ^^ so maybe you're having this problem too...)*

Comment: Wonderful, it worked! I am sorry that is such a noob mistake.  Now I have successfully migrated my sites.  Let me know if anyone wants help with their migration.

Comment: Don't worry about mistakes : we all make mistakes ; and this one was quite funny, actually, the first time I saw it ^^  Have fun !

Answer (score 2):

You could have avoided that by only migrating the sites/ directory. Extract the latest version on your new server and copy the modules, themes, and settings from your old site. Of course the database will need to move also.

This assumes your site is up to date and you haven't modified the drupal core. You may have a custom install profile to copy over too.

Comment: I have done this with my most recent migration.  Much easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are some important things to keep in mind before migrating from one Drupal instance to another

```
1. Optimize the tables before exporting the database.
 a) By clearing all the temporary tables
 b) By removing website cache.

For more details go through the following link:
http://goldapplesoftware.ca/blog/2011-05-reducing-drupals-disk-temporary-table-usage

2. Export database with command line so no data is lost.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your httpd/apache conf file... be sure to add:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```