# How to restore a Drupal site from a file archive on another server?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7, migration

My company recently inherited a client with a handful of sites using Drupal, and being primarily a WordPress shop, we don't really know where to start.

We were given a file archive of the web root to put on a fresh server. I'm guessing that this is a multi-site Drupal install, because there are three folders inside my /sites/ directory: all, default, and a folder describing my client.

I added new databases for the sql dumps inside sites/default/data and sites/[client]/data and referenced them in the two settings.php files where my databases are being called.

I also changed the $sites variable in sites/sites.php to reflect my new server address.

However, when I go to [server-address]/user/login and enter my username and password, all I can get to is the Drupal 7 Starter Site. Obviously, this isn't the information that I need, and I need to access my client's site.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure that someone will be able to help you as we don't see what you have. But if you see installation page, this means that your database link from settings.php wasn't detected. Also, this is normal to have "all" and "default" directories in "sites" directory.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems like a variation of the question [Drupal to Drupal Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412681/drupal-to-drupal-migration) : did you correctly restore the **.htaccess** file(s) also? Those are "hidden" ( filename starts with a '.'), not shown by default by some FTP transfer softwares.

If that doesn't help, maybe these questions might help:

- [Migrating Drupal Site on SAME server;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116419/migrating-drupal-site-on-same-server) :
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925677/migrating-live-drupal-site-to-localhost :