# Migrating Drupal Site on same server

Tags: mysql, drupal, migration, cpanel

I have finished developing my new Drupal site to replace an old HTML static site.

I chose to install the Drupal site on Public HTML folder on the main domain here;

**www.my-site.co.uk/development-site**

I would now like to remove the old HTML static site and replace with this site.

Do I just delete all the HTML files from the old site, excluding **/development-site** file, then move all the contents of this file into the public HTML folder?

Also, with the database being on the same server, I am guessing I would not need to change anything on the settings.php file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed your site correctly, you can move the **development-site** content to another location of your server without errors.

You should copy your old HTML site in other place. And then move your Drupal.

The `settings.php` no needs changes, assuming that your database is in the same folder (localhost configuration);

The only problem you can have is the situation of some static url in your site linking to the **development-site** folder. If you are sure there are no links like that in your Drupal. Let's move your site.